# Method not found in derived class inherited from abstract class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, methods, abstract-class

```
abstract class superclass {
  public abstract void method();
}
class subclass extends superclass {
  public void method() {
    //do something
  }
  public void newMethod() {
    //do something
  }
}
public class mainclass {
  public static void main(String[]args) {
    superclass abc = new subclass();
    abc.method();
    abc.newMethod(); //cannot find symbol error
  }
}
```

In the above example, can new methods be not written in the derived class of an abstract class? If I do that, it raises an error.

Comment: You should follow Java naming conventions. Class names should start uppercase.

Comment: @maloomeister This is just an example. My main program has all class names starting with uppercase.

Comment: You defined `abc` to be of type `superclass`. But `superclass` does not define `newMethod`. So to call `newMethod()` on it you need to cast it to `subclass` beforehand. -> `((subclass) abc).newMethod();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When extending a Superclass you can in fact add more methods. Hoevery in this case you assign your `new subclass()` to a variable of the type `superclass` which means that you will only have access to the methods wich are a part of that type. In this case that's only `method()`. If you want to use both methods you should write instead:

```java
subclass abc = new subclass();
```

or cast it on demand:

```
((subclass) abc).newMethod();
```